# Import databricks notebook (dynamic content) using workspace api import method

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to import databricks notebook using workspace api import method. Content of notebook should be dynamic. I am trying using below code but it gives error:

> malfunctioned request

request contains invalid json body. I have tried converting `content` to base64 encoded data and pass it in payload still it gives same error. main thing I want to achieve is , I want to generate content of notebook dynamically.

```
import requests
import os
import json

ctx = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())
host_name = ctx['extraContext']['api_url']
host_token = ctx['extraContext']['api_token']
notebook_path = ctx['extraContext']['notebook_path']
new_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(notebook_path), 'New name')

data = {
  "content": "print(hellow world)",
  "path": new_path,
  "language": "PYTHON",
  "overwrite": true,
  "format": "SOURCE"
}

response = requests.post(
    '{host_name}/api/2.0/workspace/import',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {host_token}'},
    data = data
  ).json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several problems here:

- per [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import), the `content` field should be base64-encoded, so you need to do it as:

```py
import base64
data = {
  "content": base64.b64encode("print(hellow world)".encode()),
  ...
}
```

- the payload should be a JSON, but you're using `data` parameter that sends data as multipart form data (see [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)).  You need to use `json` parameter instead:

```py
response = requests.post(
    f'{host_name}/api/2.0/workspace/import',
    headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {host_token}'},
    json = data
  ).json()
```

- You're trying to substitute host name, but you're using just string, not f-string, so you need to change `'{host_name}/api/2.0/workspace/import'` to `f'{host_name}/api/2.0/workspace/import'`