# Transfer files saved in filestore to either the workspace or to a repo

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-repos

I built a machine learning model:

```
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

which I can save to the filestore by:

```
filename = "/dbfs/FileStore/lr_model.pkl"
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(lr, f)
```

Ideally, I wanted to save the model directly to a workspace or a repo so I tried:

```
filename = "/Users/user/lr_model.pkl"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(lr, f)
```

but it is not working because the file is not showing up in the workspace.

The only alternative I have now is to transfer the model from the filestore to the workspace or a repo, how do I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store file in DBFS (`/FileStore/...`), it's in your account (data plane). While notebooks, etc. are in the Databricks account (control plane). By design, you can't import non-code objects into a workspace.  But Repos now has support for [arbitrary files](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html#enable-support-for-arbitrary-files-in-databricks-repos), although only one direction - you can access files in Repos from your cluster running in data plane, but you can't write into Repos (at least not now).  You can:

- Either export model to your local disk & commit, then pull changes into Repos
- Use [Workspace API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace) to put file (only source code as of right now) into Repos. Here is an [answer that shows how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487876/import-databricks-notebook-dynamic-content-using-workspace-api-import-method/70492941#70492941).

But really, you should use MLflow that is built-in into Azure Databricks, and it will help you by [logging the model file, hyper-parameters, and other information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/mlflow/tracking).  And then you can work with this model using APIs, command tools, etc., for example, to [move the model between staging & production stages using Model Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/mlflow/model-registry), [deploy model to AzureML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/mlflow/scikit-learn-model-deployment-on-azure-ml), etc.

Comment: @ Alex I had a similar issue. Can you please suggest the best way to read the mount file for pyreadstat read_xport function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package